# Issue with accessing this.$router.params in VueRouter

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Slight strange one. i thought I knew how VueRouter works, but I am having trouble accessing a param that I am passing into a bound router-link.

Within `'@/views/Home.vue'`:

```
<router-link
    class="ml-1"
    :to="{ name: 'home', params: { activeInstructorSet: false }}"
>
    Switch
</router-link>
```

I have the following routes:

`'@/routes/index.js`:f

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "home",
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "@/views/Home.vue"),
  }
];
```

So I know the named route exists.

However, when clicking on the link - nothing.

`'@/views/Home.vue'`

```
created() {
    console.log(this.$route);
    this.activeInstructorSet = this.$route.params.activeInstructorSet;
},
```

I believe the issue is that this is within the Home.vue component/view - and is pushing to the same `view`, so nothing is happening...when navigating back to the route with name 'home', the `created()` call isn't made? Where/when should I be accessing `this.$route.params` in the lifecycle methods?

Versions:

```
"vue": "^2.6.10",
"vue-router": "^3.1.3",
```

Comment: Sounds like https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes. I would add that it is an abuse of routing to pass a param that isn't included in the path.

Comment: So they should be query params?

Answer (score 0):

Since your view has already been created, the `created` lifecycle hook is not called again.
Vue Router has it's own lifecycle methods that you can use for this purpose, see [Vue Router In-Component Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards)

In your case, you want to use 
`beforeRouteUpdate`.

An example implementation would be:

```
beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
    console.log(to);
    this.activeInstructorSet = to.params.activeInstructorSet;
    next();
},
```

Comment: @WindUpLordVexxos What does *'doesn't work'* mean? Do you mean that the proposed solution does not appear to be an answer to your question? If not, why not? Or do you mean that it sounds correct in theory but you're unable to obtain the desired end result? In that case you should provide extra information based on your attempt to debug the problem. As always with debugging the key is to establish which step is faulty rather than only considering the final result. At the very least you should tell us whether you are seeing the console logging.

Comment: @skirtle The answer is too vague. So the value of `this.activeInstructorSet` is `undefined` when attempting to access it after the router change. I have managed to fix the issue by adding the params into `computed { activeInstructorSet() { return this.$route.params.activeInstructorSet; } }`. So my conclusion was, that the `beforeRouteUpdate` is the wrong hook to be using on the component level. The component was also stripped back to allow for any errors that may have come through incorrectly reassigning a value.

Comment: I'd rather say "too vague" is your first comment ;-) The hook definitely works. Now that I checked your question again, I think you made a mistake elsewhere, so I am not sure how exactly your current solution is working. In your route definition, you don't have any params at all. The route is just "home", no parameters. When you then create your router link, you probably want to add `query` instead of `params`. Then access it via `to.query.activeInstructorSet`. See https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#programmatic-navigation